# Android Connect to WCF

Tags: android, wcf

I could not connect to  WCF service , but it alsways i get "**Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!**"
This is service file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
 ......
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
  <add key="HO" value=""/>
  <add key="AutoUpdatePath" value="E:\AutoUpdate"/>
</appSettings>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0" maxBufferSize="2000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="2000000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NewBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior" name="XONT.Common.Data.PDAServiceBLL.MyPDAService">
    <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.11:7979/mytService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="My.Common.Data.PDAServiceBLL.MyPDAService"/>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.11:7979/mytService"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and my android calling method like this
     **EDIT:**
Here is Android calling WCF usig KSOAP2

```
 public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException 
     {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
        request.addProperty("strExec", "WAT2"); //variable name, value. I got the variable name, from the wsdl file!
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request
        AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);  
        httpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent 
                                     //message was (httpTransport.requestDump)
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response
        return result;
     }
```

This is my C# method:

```
   namespace My.Common.Data.PDAServiceDAL
   {
    public class MyPDAServiceDAL
    {
     EcecutiveCode = "";
     sqlConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     }
       public List<string> loadPassword_Executive(string strExec)
        {
            EcecutiveCode = strExec;
            sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            SqlCommand com;
            SqlDataReader dr;
            try
            {
                string sql = "select Password,BusinessUnit,PrimaryTerritoryCode,DefaultSalesWarehouse,DefaultSalesLocation from RD.Executive where ExecutiveCode = '" + strExec + "'";
                com = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
                sqlCon.Open();
                dr = com.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                    list.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    list.Add(dr[2].ToString());
                    list.Add(dr[3].ToString());
                    list.Add(dr[4].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteToLog(e);
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
                //dr.Close();
                //dr.Dispose();
            }

            return list;
        }
```

and in Activity i called:

```
  try {
SoapObject result=soap(METHOD_NAME, SOAP_ACTION, NAMESPACE, APPURL);            
 Log.w("log_tag",result.getPropertyCount()+  "=====" + result.getProperty(0).toString());
  } catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

**Error is :**
I got error message Like this  **Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

> **
>   **Edited:**
>   How we can increase the time? please help me

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending empty POST request without any HTTP header or body. Basic HTTP binding expects valid SOAP request with SOAP action which is used to determine called operation. Anyway I think that should give your some error instead of timeout. Can you at least open this from your android device: `http://192.168.1.11:7979/mytService?wsdl` ?

Doing all SOAP communication manually is quite complex. You should use some library which will help you consuming SOAP services - check [kSoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/).

Comment: Thanks. I tried with this http://192.168.1.11:7979/mytService?wsdl still i am getting same error.

Comment: In such case your service is not running or your android device is not able to connect to the computer hosting the service.

Comment: I am not familer in C# WCF. Its not running on IIS server.Its a windows component.In my organization they gave WCF through that i have to push the data to android.Service is running.I want to know C# WCF without running inside sever can we access method?

Comment: Service will not push data to your device. Your device will have to pull data from the service. Your component must "run" and service must be hosted - place the http://192.168.1.11:7979/mytService or http://192.168.1.11:7979/mytService?wsdl into your browser. If you get some error your service is not running.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This service is working fine now. how can access loadPassword_Executive(String) method?

Comment: I updated my code. now I am using KSoap2 . I got error message **org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: END_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body (position:END_TAG </{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}s:Fault>@1:717 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4050dbf0)  **

Comment: Now is working It wrote with SOAP_ACTION name. Now the problem is **Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
**

Comment: Thanks  Ladislav Mrnka. This is working in emulator .Problem is same thing not working in the actual phone.Please help me